# Last Modified timestamp

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add the last modified timestamp on a webpage but I want the date to change only one the page is modified.

Here is the code I am using:

```
      <script>
         var date = document.lastModified;
         document.write("Last Modified: "+date);
      </script>
```

But this is showing the current date, so each time I visit the page I see today's date. How can I change to have the date updated only when the page is updated?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That is because the js file gets sent to the client browser and the browser is executing that command to check on the lastModified - being current data/time of the client.

I do not see a way to get it from js - you would have to put that information from server side - will not be possible to read it on client side.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use JS here because "lastModified" generates on runtime.
"lastModified" should be part of static page content (like Last Modified:
10/10/2020) or generated by BE and delivered to your page with ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get this information by using only js. In this case you would need a server to keep track of the changes being made to a page and request this information with an http call.